# GetExternalLoginInfo returns 'null' on Google OWIN provider

Tags: asp.net, oauth, owin, katana

I've got a nearly stock ASP.NET MVC template application from Visual Studio 2013. It was created using the following settings:

> Create > Project > Web > ASP.NET Web Application > OK > MVC, Individual User Accounts > OK

I'm attempting to log in using the OWIN Google provider and having issues.

OWINs `Configuration` method looks like this:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        var google = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = "xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "xxxxxxxxx-yyyyyyyyy"
        };

        google.Scope.Add("profile");
        google.Scope.Add("email");

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(google);
```

I click the `Google` provider button on the web page, authenticate with google, get referred back to `ExternalLoginCallback`. At this point, the process breaks down at this line:

> var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

loginInfo is `null`, which redirects me back to the Login page without any visible errors.

Answer (score 5):

I'm responding to an old question here, but for anyone in the future who may encounter this problem, the solution that worked for me was to enable the "Google+ API" using the API Manager from the Google Developers Console.

Comment: This worked for me, I have just need to wait about 5 minutes probably to let google apply changes or something like that... Thanks!

Comment: this worked for me, really strange that all other workaround given didnt work... thanks PaulPerkins